# Automate IntelliJ "Export to Database"

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, database-dump

I am using IntelliJ and its database plugin to export data from a table on one database to a table on another database.

[image]

The tool works brilliantly, but I need to perform this task repeatedly.

Is there a way I can automate this so that it runs according some some schedule, of say, once a day?

I'm happy to code this up in Python, but I don't want to have to re-invent the tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality as *database jobs* which could be run by the schedule in DataGrip itself. But there is a [**Macros**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-macros-in-the-editor.html?search=macros) functionality which you can try: when you record  repetitive procedures you do frequently to automate it and then [execute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/playing-back-macros.html) them easily (from the Menu or via the shortcut).